# designing a RESTful get with many to many relationship parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

```
DogId (n:n) WalkerId
WalkerId (n:n) WalkPatternId
WalkPatternId (n:n) DogId
```

I need to pass `DogId, WalkerId, WalkPatternId`to my GET method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int dogid, int walkerId, int walkPatternId)
{
  return _walkingService(dogid, walkerId, walkPatternId);
}
```

It doesn't seem to RESTful to have the client GET against a URI that looks like this:

```
http://mydomain/2342/5312/4345243
```

On the other hand, I can't do a `FromBody`on a GET.

**How do I define a RESTful GET method that accepts 3 parameters, all having a many to many relationship with each other?**

Comment: _"It doesn't seem to RESTful"_ - define "RESTful", or this is going to be opinion-based.

Comment: well, i'm no expert, but i may have erroneously thought that you are not supposed to include a body in a get method

Comment: @CodeCaster would you go with body or parameters in URL?